# How can I make a Gif's magenta background transparent in Visual C# Express?

Tags: c#, gif

I am trying to do this for a beginner game project I am working on; I would like if it would be possible to see what is behind the image, then. My gifs have a magenta (255, 0, 255) background around the animated character, and I would like it to be completely transparent.

Answer (score 0):

The sprites have a magenta background for a reason. What graphics library are you using for your sprites? The default chroma key color in XNA is RGB(255,0,255). Any pixel that is magenta will be drawn as transparent. Your other option is to change the images in a photo editing tool.